# IE "automatically detect settings" gets unchecked

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer

we need to have the "automatically detect settings" on in order for users to connect to the internet while in the office.  But at times, the setting is unchecked when the user takes the laptop home or connects outside of the office.  So when they return, they have to go back and check the setting on again.

Is there anyway to change that so it always stays on no matter where they are connected?

Thanks for any help you can provide

Comment: Instead of worrying about controlling it outside the building, just use Group Policy in the office to (re)set that setting when they hook back into the domain.

Answer (score 1):

See if these steps work for you.

1. Open the Group Police Editor(press [image] + <kbd>R</kbd>, type `gpedit.msc` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>).
2. Navigate to `User Configuration` - `Policies` - `Windows Settings` - `Internet Explorer Maintenance` - `Connection` - `Automatic Browser Configuration`.
   [image]

[`This`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc726038.aspx) microsoft link can be useful too.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this using a normal group policy, Microsoft provides two methods for this in the group policy editor, using the methods described here:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cb6abb30-4360-4d3d-93fc-61823b2a5c20/turn-off-auto-detect-settings-in-ie-using-gpo?forum=winserverGP

In combination with the ones described here:
http://fbinotto.blogspot.com/2012/06/ie-gpo-automatically-detect-settings.html